# Self is not passed to the class method in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, class, oop, object

I am trying the following python code:

```
import sqlite3
class database:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("warehousedb.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (admin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT)")
        self.cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, product_price TEXT)")
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = 'admin' AND `password` = 'admin'")

        if self.cursor.fetchone() is None:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `admin` (username, password) VALUES('admin', 'admin')")
            self.conn.commit()


    def __del__(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def Execute_SQL(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.conn.commit()

    def Get_SQL(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def Get_SQL_One_Rec(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

Then when trying this code:

```
db = database()    
st = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '" + USERNAME.get() + "' AND `password` = '" + PASSWORD.get() + "'"
rec = db.Get_SQL_One_Rec(st)
```

I am getting the following error:

rec = db.Get_SQL_One_Rec(st)
    TypeError: Get_SQL_One_Rec() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sql'

I can see from the Python Documentation that the Self object is automatically passed, so why I am getting this error?
[image: the error]

Comment: Did u instantiate the `database` class beforehand ?

Comment: Are you not using a class? Class. Instance is only passed to instances of a class, not to the class itself

Comment: As an aside, this line does nothing: `global __conn, __cursor # private variable`. What did you intend it to do? Note also, Python *does not have private variables*

Comment: Don't use double underscores on names. This is not a convention you want to use; use _single_ underscores to _imply_ that something is supposed to be private. Double underscores invoke name mangling and just a mess. You cannot have truly private variables in Python.

Comment: I did instantiate the database class beforehand.

Comment: I am using the class in my code... I am using
db = database()

Comment: Hi juanpa.arrivillaga, Python do have public and private modifiers. Check this link: https://radek.io/2011/07/21/private-protected-and-public-in-python/

Comment: roganjosh, check this link: https://radek.io/2011/07/21/private-protected-and-public-in-python/

Comment: The reason why I am using the line 
global __conn, __cursor # private variable
Is because I want to make these variables available in the class methods

Comment: That link is simply wrong. Python does not have private, only a convention that attributes that are not part of the public API are prefixed with a *single underscore* a double-underscore is for *name-mangling*, to prevent collisions in subclasses, it is not private. Anyway, your `global` statement doesn't do anything

Comment: Please listen to what you are being told by experienced Python programmers. Python does *not* have private variables, and that `global` line is nonsense and should be removed.

Comment: Juanpa.Arrivillaga and Daniel Roseman, I modified the code. I removed all underscores and the global line and still getting the same error...

Comment: By the way, see the last slide in this link: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/331/fall10/notes/python/python3.ppt.pdf it says that there are private modifiers in Python. This slides are a university slides and they are not wrong.

Comment: Works for me as expected, without Error. [Edit] your Question and show how do you instantiate `db`?

Comment: Thanks for allowing me to edit. I done some edit and attached a screenshot of the error. Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://tpcg.io/gzRUI0
Its working as it should

Comment: Muhammad Bilal, it didn't work in PyCharm... the database class is in different file. Please see the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have provided works, see this link:

https://repl.it/@zlim00/self-is-not-passed-to-the-class-method-in-python

The only difference compared to your code is that this sqllite database is in memory instead of a file. So if the code doesn't work for you, the error lies in parts of the code that you have not submitted.

**Code (in case the link is removed):**

```
import sqlite3
class database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (admin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT)")
        self.cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, product_price TEXT)")
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = 'admin' AND `password` = 'admin'")

        if self.cursor.fetchone() is None:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `admin` (username, password) VALUES('admin', 'admin')")
            self.conn.commit()


    def __del__(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def Execute_SQL(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.conn.commit()

    def Get_SQL(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def Get_SQL_One_Rec(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = database()    
    st = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '" + 'admin' + "' AND `password` = '" + 'admin' + "'"
    rec = db.Get_SQL_One_Rec(st)
    print(rec)
```

Comment: Thanks SimonF... It works like a magic.

Comment: But still not understand why, is that because the MS Windows? Even when I restore my old code but with your :memory: modification it works.

Comment: The :memory: change is not to make it work, only to avoid creating a file and to make sure the starting point is an empty db every run for testing. It should make no difference, so code should work with whichever database.

Comment: Thank you SimonF and thanks to all who helped me in this. I am very much appreciated.